# select() Alternative for Windows for both console input and sockets?

Tags: perl, sockets

For Linux, select() works for both sockets and console input.  But on windows, it only works for sockets.

This is problematic because I am looking to write a client in perl console where I can connect to a server, print and parse messages, and be informed when the user inputs commands into the console.  Something like a chatroom, when I can both print messages to the console and read user input to send messages.

Is there any alternative to do this on Windows? Or am I forced to use Window Applications instead of the console?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately not. In fact, this is one of the core problems facing porting asynchronous software onto Windows.

About the closest thing you could get is `WaitForMultipleObjectsEx`, which has all sorts of interesting and well-known issues with it (such as its 64 handle limit, and how it copes with than one handle being ready at once). But if you want to multiple console and network socket IO, it's about the only option on Windows.